# Changing color Axis in Highchart Choropleth

Tags: r, highcharts, choropleth

I'm fairly new to visualizing maps on R and I'm trying to change the legends in a motion choropleth. 
My code is as under

```
ds <- a21 %>% 
  group_by(fips) %>% 
  do(item = list(
    fips = first(.$fips),
    sequence = .$freq,
    value = first(.$freq))) %>% 
  .$item

hc <- highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = ds,
                name = "complaints",
                mapData = uscountygeojson,
                joinBy = "fips",
                borderWidth = 0.01) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops()) %>%  
  hc_title(text = "patient complaints") %>% 
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", reversed = TRUE,
            floating = TRUE, align = "right") %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>% 
  hc_motion(
    enabled = TRUE,
    axisLabel = "year",
    labels = sort(unique(a21$year)),
    series = 0,
    updateIterval = 50,
    magnet = list(
      round = "floor",
      step = 0.1
    )
  )
```

Screenshot of the existing result:

[image]

As of now I see R automatically creates colorbins of frequencies

I wish to change this to a set of custom values in my dataframe.

A snippet of my dataframe is as under

```
a21:

      year  fips   freq            q
1     2004  1001      3 1st Quantile
2     2005  1001      0 1st Quantile
3     2006  1001      4 1st Quantile
4     2007  1001      0 1st Quantile
5     2008  1001      0 1st Quantile
6     2009  1001      0 1st Quantile
```

I want the column q as color axis labels

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to associate column q with a color (perhaps as another column in the dataframe) and then use those colors in conjunction with the color_stops function.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/us/us-all"))

set.seed(1234)

data_fake <- mapdata %>% 
  select(code = `hc-a2`) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1e5 * abs(rt(nrow(.), df = 10)))

colors <- c("red", "blue", "green" , "yellow")

hcmap("countries/us/us-all", data = data_fake, value = "value",
      joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code"), name = "Fake data",
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
      borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
      tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2, valuePrefix = "$", valueSuffix = 
      "USD"))%>%
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = "blue", maxColor = "red", 
  stops = color_stops(n=length(colors), colors = colors))
```